# Is it possible to open fancybox with a class in href?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have this link to open my div #fancyContent in a fancybox:

```
<a class="fancybox" href="#fancyContent"></a>
```

Here I have my div #fancyContent:

```
<div id="fancyContent">
//here I have some content
</div>
```

And it is working fine,

But I want to pass my `<div id="fancyContent">` to class `<div class="fancyContent">`, because I have more than one div with `id="fancyContent"`, so it not seems correct to use the same id many times.

Do you know if this is possible?

Here I have my script to start fancybox:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        maxWidth    : 800,
        fitToView   : false,
        width       : '80%',
        height      : '80%',
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick  : false,
        }

    });
})
```

Comment: What happens when you use a class name then?

Comment: Fancybox dont open, and I get in my url: http://localhost/projet/.fancyContent  ...and I tried like this: <a class="fancybox" href=".fancyContent"></a>

Comment: I have a similar problem with jqGrid. I assign a random ID to the div then use that as the selector. i.e. `$( "#" + $(".fancybox").attr("id"))`...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I understood your answer. But If I give random ids to my div, then I will have my div without format formatting..

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "div without format formatting"

Comment: Because I have my div #fancyContent with css styles, and If I call this div #fancyContent1, #fancyContent2,... I dont have that id´s on my css stylesheet!

Comment: You can give your divs multiple classes e.g. `<div class="fancy fancy1">

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I didnt know that, and now, it was easy and I already have this work like I want :)